# reducing the stl file size for a bsplinecurve tube

Tags: 3d-printing, stl-format

I want to create a tube structure in STL format with very few triangles because it will be a large array(200x200) in the final design. But the issue is I tried MaxCellMeasure -> Infinity, and it seems to only change the number of triangles for t2 and t3(which are the straight parts). The Tube[BSplineCurve...] part still has as many segments as before. I was looking for something in the tube function and in the export function, but I did not find anything useful. The tube is turning 90 degrees, I don't mind if it is not turning very smoothly. So is there a way to reduce the triangles for the curved tube?

```
t2 = Tube[{{-1, 0, -100}, {-1, 0, 0}}, 5];
t1 = Tube[
   BSplineCurve[{{-1, 0, 0}, {-1, 0, 100}, {0, 100, 100}}, 
    SplineDegree -> 2], 5];
t3 = Tube[{{0, 100, 100}, {0, 200, 100}}, 5];

t = {t1, t2, t3};

a = Graphics3D[t]
cb = DiscretizeGraphics[t, MaxCellMeasure -> Infinity];

Export["three.stl", cb, "STL", "BinaryFormat" -> False]
Import["three.stl"]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

One way to do this is to manually control the amount of plane-intersection for the tube made by the `BSpline` curve.

For the original file we have:

> 253kb, 636 vertices, 1260 polygons

**First change:**
We discretize the spline tube to have only 10 anchor points:

```
t1 = Tube[
   BSplineFunction[{{-1,0,0},{-1,0,100},{0,100,100}}, SplineDegree->2] /@ Range[0,1,1/10]
     , 5];
```

> 137kb, 351 vertices, 690 polygons

**Second change:**
Currently, every tube-part has an endcap and they're intersecting each other. However, the middle point does not need them and we can join the tube sections.

```
tAll = Tube[{{-1, 0, -100}, {-1, 0, 0}}~
    Join~(BSplineFunction[{{-1, 0, 0}, {-1, 0, 100}, {0, 100, 100}}, 
       SplineDegree -> 2] /@ Range[0, 1, 1/10])~
    Join~{{0, 100, 100}, {0, 200, 100}}, 5];

a = Graphics3D[tAll]
cb = DiscretizeGraphics[tAll, MaxCellMeasure -> Infinity];
```

> 91kb, 227 vertices, 450 polygons

**Third, optional change:**
Do you need the round endcaps? If not, we can replace them with no endcaps or flat ones. I will add flat ones.

```
a = Graphics3D[{CapForm["Butt"], tAll}]
cb = DiscretizeGraphics[a, MaxCellMeasure -> Infinity];
```

> 78kb, 197 vertices, 390 polygons

You can fine-tune the amount of polygons just by changing the step-size in the `Range` command.

**EDIT**: Btw, `MaxCellMeasure -> Infinity` does nothing, but actual values help. For example, with `MaxCellMeasure -> 200` we get 26kb, 67 vertices, 130 polygons.

Comment: Thanks so much. It helps a lot.